# JavaScript - Iterating through objects in instance of object 'class'

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I'm trying to iterate through all objects inside the instance of an object using pure JavaScript.

I tried something like this:

```
function a(){
    this.iterate = function(){
        for (var obj in this){
            console.log(obj);
        }
    }
}

var A = new a();
A.insertedValue = 20;
A.iterate();
```

When doing this, instead of logging for example "20" for insertedValue it simply logs the name of the variable like "insertedValue".

Is there either a better way of looping through all objects in an instance of a object or a way to get the values from the objects I'm looping through?

Answer (score 4):

> Is there either a better way of looping trough all objects in an
>   instance of a object or a way to get the values from the objects I'm
>   looping trough?

Because you are simply printing the key inside `this` rather than its value using `this[obj]`.

Make it

```
function a(){
    this.iterate = function(){
        for (var obj in this){
            console.log(this[obj]); //observe that this line has changed
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you're doing it is largely correct, it's just that `for-in` loops through the **names** of the object's properties, not their values. So to output the property's value, you use `this[name]`:

```
function a(){
    this.iterate = function(){
        for (var name in this){
            console.log(name + "=" + this[name]);
        }
    };
}
```

Note that `for-in` will loop through the enumerable properties of the object, including ones it inherits from its prototype. If you just want *own* properties, and not inherited ones, you can either check whether the property is an "own" property through `hasOwnProperty`:

```
function a(){
    this.iterate = function(){
        for (var name in this){
            if (this.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                console.log(name + "=" + this[name]);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Or use the handy `Object.keys`, which gives you an array of own enumerable properties:

```
function a(){
    this.iterate = function(){
        Object.keys(this).forEach(function(name) {
            console.log(name + "=" + this[name]);
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: Cool, but a link to this bible-like answer would have sufficed :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476

Comment: @gurvinder372: Well, that's about looping through arrays and array-like things, rather than objects. But... :-)